# How to find a string that is delimited by a certain start and end character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to make an array of strings based on start and end characters using regular expression.

An example will help me explanation.
Considering '$' as my starting identifier and '|' as my ending identifier from the below string

> stack **$over|** flow **$stack|** exchange

Regular expression  should find **over** and **stack** in the above string.

[Edited to include code snippets in OP's comments...]

```
string testingString = "stack $over| flow $stack| exchange"; 
var pattern = @"(?$.*?|)"; // also tried @"\$[^|]\|" 
foreach (var m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(testingString, pattern)) {     
    Response.Write(m ); 
} 
// output == stack $over| flow $stack| exchange
```

Comment: Then you should ... do that. Or at least *try* to do it. [What Have you Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: (?$.*?|) Tried something like this but i know very little about regular expression

Comment: That would be a good addition to your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use look-behind and look-aheads to exclude the start and end delimiter form the match.

```
string testingString = @"stack $over| flow $stack| exchange";

MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches
    (testingString,
            @"       
                (?<=\$)  # This is a lookbehind, it ensure there is a $ before the string
                [^|]*    # Match any character that is not a |
                (?=\|)   # This is a lookahead,it ensures that a | is ahead the pattern
            "
            , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

The `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` is a useful option to be able to write readable regexes and use also comments in the regexes.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions `$` is a special character meaning "match the end of the string".
For a literal `$` you need to escape it, try `\$`.

Similarly `|` is a special character in regex and needs to be escaped.

Try `\$.*?\|` or `\$[^|]+\|`.

Learn about regular expressions from the net, for example [here](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx).

[UPDATE] 
In response to your comment, you want to *extract* text delimited by `$` and `|`, not split on it. Try [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) instead of `Regex.Split`.

```
Regex t = new Regex(@"\$([^|]+)\|");
MatchCollection allMatches = t.Matches("stack $over| flow $stack| exchange");
```

Comment: i tried both but not working . i can change my ending character '|'. If that is thee cause of problem

Comment: Why don't you give your input string, the exact code you used, and the result. It would help us to help you greatly.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee you forgot a `+` after your complemented character class, otherwise your answer works